# Libgdx No signing identity found matching '/(?i)iPhone Developer|iOS Development/'

Tags: android-studio, deployment, libgdx, certificate, robovm

I would fill my app I'm doing with Android libgdx and study, using robovm , but I did not recognize the certificate .

The certificate from xcode preferences correctly was downloaded , and then usually always worked .... what I did because it renew expired and then I re-downloaded with xCode .

Does anyone know advise me how to solve ? Thank you

```
    [ERROR] Couldn't compile app
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No signing identity found matching '/(?i)iPhone Developer|iOS Development/'
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.SigningIdentity.find(SigningIdentity.java:69)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.AppleDeviceTarget.init(AppleDeviceTarget.java:1089)
    at org.robovm.compiler.config.Config.build(Config.java:938)
    at org.robovm.compiler.config.Config.access$5200(Config.java:94)
    at org.robovm.compiler.config.Config$Builder.build(Config.java:1606)
    at org.robovm.idea.compilation.RoboVmCompileTask.compileForRunConfiguration(RoboVmCompileTask.java:206)
    at org.robovm.idea.compilation.RoboVmCompileTask.execute(RoboVmCompileTask.java:73)
    at com.intellij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver.executeCompileTasks(CompileDriver.java:627)
    at com.intellij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver.access$400(CompileDriver.java:88)
    at com.intellij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver$3.run(CompileDriver.java:410)
    at com.intellij.compiler.progress.CompilerTask.run(CompilerTask.java:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robovm/yaeV-q2NgmY

It says:

```
1. Open up Keychain Access.
2. Show expired certificates by going to View > Show Expired Certificates.
3. Navigate to the System keychain and delete the expired WWDR Certificate.
4. Download the new WWDR Certificate [here][1] and import it into your keychain.
```

I did not have to do point 4. The new certificate was already there.